# Can I temporarily pause/queue Postfix SMTP sending to a specific domain?

Tags: email, smtp, postfix, mail-server

I'd like to temporarily queue all mail to a particular domain, but allow all others to send right away.

For example, if a user on `mydomain.com` sends an email to `recipient-domain.com`, I'd like to wait before actually sending it.  Ideally it remains in the queue until the temporary hold is removed.  But, all other domains should send just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can:

1) copy `smtp` transport in master.cf and rename copy `ondemand`

```
ondemand unix - - n - - smtp
```

2) list ondemand transport in [`defer_transports`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#defer_transports) option

```
defer_transports = ondemand
```

3) Use transport map to select `ondemand` transport for deliveries to recipient-domain.com

```
recipient-domain.com   ondemand
```

Comment: And then how do I demand a release of these queued emails?

Comment: ondemand documentation suggests equivalent of `senmail -q`  command.  As I understand it may be  `postque -s recipient-domain.com` usehttps://linux.die.net/man/1/postqueue